# The regular expression shows me the opposite of what I want in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to write only numbers in the textbox3 but it shows me the opposite, I mean only letters. When I use @"\D" like a pattern it work. Why?

```
    public String NingunCaracterEspecial(Control ctrlRegresar)
    {
        String strRegresar = ctrlRegresar.Text;
        String pattern = @"\d";
        String replacement = "";

        return Regex.Replace(strRegresar, pattern, replacement);
    } 

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox3.Text = NingunCaracterEspecial(textBox1);
    }
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, what exactly do you want, only digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood from your question:

- You want to leave all digits intact.
- You want to remove (replace with an empty string) all letters.

So, the *pattern* that you indicate is what will be replaced.

If you indicate `\d`, this will replace all digits, as `\d` matches a digit. `\D` is the complement thereof, so if you replace `\D`, everything that is *not* a digit (that is, including letters) will get replaced.

Answer (score 2):

> When I use @"\D" like a pattern it work. Why?

`\D` is anything that is *not* a digit.

So you seem to be *replacing* anything that is not a digit, hence leaving only digits, which is what you want.